# Java program using Sockets does not work when used by Windows 10 users

Tags: java, sockets, networking, client-server

Hey I dont think any code is needed here as the connection works fine with remote computers using windows 7. I wrote a simple client program and server program that hosts a chat client using java Sockets. The port is properly forwarded and my firewall is set up to allow these connections. Unfortunately no windows 10 users i give the client to have been able to get it to connect. The computer the server is running on is windows 8 if that matters at all. The connection still doesn't work with defender disabled on the client computer. Any ideas?

Edit: Code

Server:

```
package testserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TestServer {
private static final int PORT = 53274;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        try 
        {
            while(true)
            {
                new Handler(listener.accept()).start();
            }
        } finally 
        {
            listener.close();
        }
    }
     public static class Handler extends Thread 
    {
        private String name;
        private Socket socket;
        private BufferedReader in;
        private PrintWriter out;

        public Handler(Socket socket) throws IOException 
        {
          this.socket = socket;
          in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
          out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        }



    }    
}
```

Client:

```
package testclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TestClient {
    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;

    private void run() throws IOException 
    {
        String serverAddress = "omitting my actual address here";
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 53274);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        TestClient client = new TestClient();
        client.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any logs?

Comment: Without code and logs we can't guess what could be wrong.

Comment: sorry i'm going to need some help here, how do i get the logs?

Comment: From your real application, create a simple test app, using the code that does the barest necessary to connect to the server and send or receive a bit of data. Should be less than 20 lines for both the client and server. Run that and see if it works. If not, post that code and your error messages. Otherwise, this question is off-topic.

Comment: I added the code. this works locally but i dont have somebody remote and on windows 7 and 10 to test if it has the same behavior. the problem is a connection timeout. As stated I believe the problem stems from windows 10 antivirus configuration, not my code.

Comment: Connect timeout -> network connectivity issue. Can you ping your server host from your client host? Telnet to the server IP:port?

Comment: I figured this out and want to clear this up in case anybody has the same issue. The off network computers were attempting to connecting using ipv6, my default connection type, however needed the ipv4 to work properly. Cheers